# Parse simple time length strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jira

Not wanting to reinvent the wheel, is there some javascript code to parse strings like "4h 3m" into minutes, the same way Jira does it.

Someone asked the same question for ruby:
[How to parse days/hours/minutes/seconds in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657309/how-to-parse-days-hours-minutes-seconds-in-ruby)

Comment: I'd ask this one over at answers.atlassian.com and then use the existing JS that JIRA provides?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of success with Date.js:
http://www.datejs.com/

Moment.js may be useful too: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, I just realized neither of those will process durations like what you're asking.